# Band-Stop Filter mask based on low/high pass filter mask OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, fft

I am looking for the way to combine images below:
[image]
[image]

into image like:

[image]

What I am doing is trying to make band stop filter with masks from butterworth low/high pass filters.
If there is no way to merge masks like that I will post my butterworth code so maybe you could help me re-implement it to do the work:

```
void Processing::lowhighpass_filter(cv::Mat &dft_Filter, int D, int n, bool highpass)
{
    dft_Filter = cv::Mat(dft_Filter.rows,dft_Filter.cols,CV_32F,cv::Scalar::all(0));

    cv::Point centre = cv::Point(dft_Filter.rows / 2, dft_Filter.cols / 2);
    double radius;

    // based on the forumla in the IP notes (p. 130 of 2009/10 version)
    for(int i = 0; i < dft_Filter.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < dft_Filter.cols; j++)
        {
            radius = (double) std::sqrt(std::pow((i - centre.x), 2.0) + std::pow((double) (j - centre.y), 2.0));
            dft_Filter.at<float>(i,j) = (float) ( 1 / (1 + std::pow((double) (radius /  D),   (double) (2 * n))));
        }
    }

    if (highpass)
    {
        dft_Filter = cv::Scalar::all(1) - dft_Filter;
        //cv::imshow("highpass_filter", dft_Filter);
    }

    cv::Mat toMerge[] = {dft_Filter, dft_Filter};
    cv::merge(toMerge, 2, dft_Filter);
}
```

I need to create the mask like on the third image, possibly with modifiable radius of inner and outer circle. Any clues?

Comment: Can you share the fixed code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize the first to [0:1] range, then per-element multiplication between these two images.
Don't forget, they are need to have CV_32FC or CV_64FC element type.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to find radius of circle in FT domain that later you assign zero values that radius for stop the frequency you want. 
If you already correct your code then share your code here so other people got help your code.